# Docker volume mount and permissions: www-data on host (33) becomes xfs (33) in Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, permissions, mount

I have trouble with a Directory mount from my host in a docker container:

- Alpine Linux [includes user xfs (33) and group xfs (33), with no www-data](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/135)
- the files on host are owned by www-data (33)
- I need these files to be accessible by nginx inside the nginx:alpine docker image

This is a fullstack situation: I am using a service stack to make files available on local lan.
the stack uses nginx:alpine, images are made available - so I cannot easily modify the Dockerimage.

Is there anything that I can do that xfs inside the Alpine Linux image does't get user and group id 33?

I tried to set PUID and PGID in the `docker-compose.yml`,
but it doesn't work (I also have trouble understanding this):

```
services:
celeryworker:
    environment:
      - PUID=33
      - PGID=33
```

**Minimal reproducable example:**

Files on the host:

```sh
cd /mnt/nfs/folder1
ls -alh
>-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 3.5M Sep 21 15:41 '02 - track.mp3'
ls -alhn
>-rwxr-xr-x 1 33 33 3.5M Sep 21 15:41 '02 - track.mp3'
less /etc/passwd | grep www-data
>www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  celeryworker:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: funkwhale/funkwhale:1.0.1
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    command: celery -A funkwhale_api.taskapp worker -l INFO --concurrency=0
    environment:
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=true
    volumes:
      - "/mnt/nfs/:/music:ro"
```

Files in the container:

```sh
docker exec -it funkwhale_celeryworker_1 /bin/bash
cd /music/folder1/
ls -alh
>-rwxr-xr-x    1 xfs      xfs         3.4M Sep 21 13:41 '02 - track1.mp3'
ls -alhn
>-rwxr-xr-x    1 33      33         3.4M Sep 21 13:41 '02 - track1.mp3'
su xfs
>This account is not available
less /etc/passwd | grep xfs
>xfs:x:33:33:X Font Server:/etc/X11/fs:/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  Does the files being owned by uid 33 present a specific problem?  Are they world-readable on the host?  (If you bind-mount files into a container, they will generally keep the same _numeric_ user and group owner and other attributes in both host and container contexts.)

Comment: Aplogies, you're right, I updated my original post.

Comment: Ah, this was my mistake: `folder1` was not world readable! Once I used chmod 755 folder1, permission was granted inside the container, even for user xfs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Late reply, but maybe it could help somebody else.. The UID:GID for `www-data` in Debian/Ubuntu doesn't match with the IDs in Alpine:

| user : group | Debian/Ubuntu (uid:gid) | Alpine (uid:gid) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| www-data : www-data | 33 : 33 | 82 : 82 |
| xfs : xfs | - | 33 : 33 |

If your host folder is owned by `www-data:www-data` (`33:33`), then inside the Alpine container this uid:gid is going to match with the uid:gid of `xfs:xfs` and you will have problems with the permissions.

To solve this issue you can change the ownership in the host to 82:82:

```
$ sudo chown -R 82:82 host_directory
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, changing permissions to world readable or ownership on the host are the only solutions. I thought there was something that I could to to the docker container only to fix this. Anyway, it works!

Comment: I am unhappy with this being flagged as the solution. Usually there is a reason why files on the host are owned by `www-data`, for example if they are managed through e.g. Nextcloud. If you change the permissions on the host to match the required permissions in the container, then Nextcloud can not access them anymore. Thus there is no more use for the data outside of the container anymore, and then you could as well just store them in a Docker volume.

Comment: You could modify the image to change the user/group that will run the container.. And yes, Docker volumes are a better option most of the time.

Comment: I disagree, docker volumes are usually only good for fast testing. Anything persistent should be integrated with your personal folder/file flow. By the way, I finally solved the issue, on my side, with nested user-mappings: My files are bind-mounted from the Hypervisor using  LXC UID Mappings (www-data -> 82 : 82 in LXC -> www-data in Alpine Docker). Unfortunately, this is not applicable beyond Proxmox.

Answer (score 0):

More details with different solutions in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/zdenekdrahos/53f16cfe902ff5f820a01b79e8c76a01)